# What icons can be added from different versions of material-ui/icons in a react project?

Tags: reactjs, icons, material-ui

I know how to add the icons, so this is not a duplicate of the "how to add material ui icons to react" questions here.

The question I have is **how do I know WHICH icons i can use depending on the specific version**, since different icons were added or removed at various points?

---

### Example of icon not working, so wondering if available

I was previously trying to add a thumbs down icon. Here is how I would normally go about adding an icon

1. In the .jsx file I would add this import

   `import AssignmentIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Assignment';`
2. Then I would add the icon

   `<AssignmentIcon/>`

But when I tried to add a thumbs down, it would not work. This is how it is listed in the poorly documented page of NPM
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/icons

[image]

The link mentioned in the NPM repo leads to another poorly documented page at https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=thumb_down&style=baseline

It just lists the icon as `thumbs_down`

I followed the same pattern that previously worked for me, I tried

```
import ThumbsDownIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbsDown';
<ThumbsDownIcon/>
```

---

### Edit

I later realized I made a typo. I could have prevented that if I could just look in my project and copy and paste the name as required. So to make even more clear the intent of my question, where exactly can I find that after I install from NPM?

Comment: Whoever voted to close should add a reason.

Comment: I voted to close because the question is mostly about a simple typo.

Comment: @thirtydot this is not about a typo, i happen to accidentally include a typo, but the MAIN portion of the question is in the title. "what icons can be added", if I add this to my react project, where could i see what which icons are available in that version.

Comment: No worries, this won't get closed anyway since there's not enough activity on the tag. And the question might be useful to someone else who struggles with renamed icons/exact icon names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Material-UI v4.3.3, there's a searchable list in the documentation:

https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/

---

You can see the listing that you have on your local disk in `node_modules\@material-ui\icons` and you will find them there.

[image]

---

In regards to your specific example, it was just a small typo:

It's `thumb_down` not `thumbs_down`.

This works:

```js
import ThumbDownIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ThumbDown';

<ThumbDownIcon />
```

---

### Further reading

**Material UI icons repo on Github:** [github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui-icons](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui-icons)

Comment: Do you know where i can see the full list of available icons? I think they vary per version?

Comment: [Here's the repo](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui-icons). It runs a script which builds all the icons from [Google's icon repo](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons). You can look [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/master/packages/material-ui-icons/src) if you really need a list from Material-UI. Or just look on your local disk in `node_modules\@material-ui\icons`. 99% of the time though, you can look at [the Material Design site](https://material.io/tools/icons/?style=baseline). Google does sometimes update the icons.